# How do I inherit default data from a module or class

Tags: ruby

I am working on an application to automate testing for SQL injection vulnerability. It is currently named Deft and is for a University project.

I want to be able to run tests from a command line, or an interactive console. I am coding several classes. (`Deft::Cli`, `Deft::Console` etc.)

Here's what I think I'd like to do.

```
module Deft
  module App
    attr_accessor :origin
    @origin = { "host" => "localhost", "port" => "80" }
  end
end

module Deft
  class Console
    include App

    def initialize
      puts origin
    end
  end
end
```

The example has been simplified, but the point is that the default values (and structure) get defined in the `Deft::App` module.

The problem as I can tell is that although `methods.grep(/origin/)` from inside a console instance does indeed give me `["origin=", "origin"]` calling `origin` returns `nil`. Instead of the values I define in `Deft::App`. It makes sense that it doesn't work, but I don't know how to make it work.

Comment: Do you want code to be able to assign to `Deft::App.origin`, or will it remain constant?

Comment: I need to be able to assign it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this?

```
module Deft
  class DefaultConsole
    attr_accessor :origin
    def initialize
      @origin = {'host' => 'localhost', 'port' => 80}
    end
  end

  class Console < DefaultConsole
    def initialize
      super
      puts origin
    end
  end
end

Deft::Console.new
# => {'host' => 'localhost', 'port' => 80}
```

Comment: This leaves me asking the question, "why _didn't_ I do it like this in the first place?!"

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps I'm taking the simplified example too literally, but one way to fix it is to get rid of the `attr_accessor` class method invocation and just make `origin` be the constant `Origin` or `ORIGIN`.

Comment: I need to be able to set the values in origin from cli and the console

Comment: Since it is going to be a `Hash`, you can set the values by methods like `replace`, `clear`, `merge`, even if it is defined as a constant. So you do not need to avoid this option if that is your only concern.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
module Deft
  module App
    attr_accessor :origin
    def init
      @origin = { "host" => "localhost", "port" => "80" }
    end
  end
end

module Deft
  class Console
    include App

    def initialize
      init
      puts origin
    end
  end
end

Deft::Console.new
```

Comment: Thank you. I came across this, but didn't like the idea of the `init` call.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone that added their input. I'm going to go ahead and answer my own question, this works as I had hoped.

```
module Deft
  module App
    @@origin = { "host" => "localhost", "port" => "80" }

    def origin        ; @@origin        ; end
    def origin=(args) ; @@origin=(args) ; end
  end
end
```

If anyone wants to copy and clean this up using attr_accesor then I'd be happy to edit this back into my question and accept their answer.

Comment: In Rails, you could use `mattr_accessor :origin`. But I dont think there is another way in Ruby.